# Expressões Regulares em python

Tags: python, regex

Como posso ler um arquivo em python procurando por palavras que se enquadram em uma expressão regular, exemplo: pesquisar datas(dd/mm/aaaa)?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363660/112052 (basta trocar o `\.` por `/` nas regex que tem lá na [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso implementando um gerador que faz uso da biblioteca [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) buscando em cada linha do arquivo todas as palavras que satisfazem o padrão definido pela expressão. Um esboço desta função seria:

```
def get_pattern_from_file(filename, expression):
  pattern = re.compile(expression)
  with open(filename) as stream:
    for line in stream:
      yield re.findall(pattern, line)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TealRuralQbasic)</sup>

Assim, você poderá iterar sobre o retorno da função e obter uma lista de todas as palavras que satisfazem a expressão por linha. Você consegue, inclusive, converter o resultado para apenas uma lista, com todas as palavras, utilizando a função [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).