# Como faço para encontrar um padrão de caracteres correspondente a uma data em um texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data

Tenho um texto em uma string, e quero usar algum método, como o `.find`, para encontrar uma sequência de caracteres no formato "dd.mm.aaaa".

Pensei em usar `.find("xx.xx.xxxx")` mas não sei o que colocar no lugar do `"x"` pra generalizar para qualquer caractere de número.

A melhor maneira é dar uma lida sobre expressões regulares?

Comment: A melhor maneira é dar uma lida sobre expressões regulares?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Para procurar padrões em um texto, uma boa solução é usar expressões regulares. No Python, elas estão disponíveis no [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Para procurar pelos números, você pode usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` (que pega qualquer dígito de 0 a 9¹). E para limitar a quantidade, você pode usar os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), como `{2}` e `{4}`, que significam, respectivamente, "2 ocorrências" e "4 ocorrências". Ou seja, `\d{2}` significa "2 ocorrências de dígitos de 0 a 9".

Então a regex fica assim:

```
import re

texto = """Data 01.02.2019, outra data 20.11.2018 etc...
Outra data 15.03.1980, etc
"""

r = re.compile(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}')
print(r.findall(texto))
```

[`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna uma lista com os trechos encontrados na string. No caso, é qualquer trecho que corresponda a `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` (dois dígitos, ponto, dois dígitos, ponto, quatro dígitos):

> ['01.02.2019', '20.11.2018', '15.03.1980']

Repare que o ponto foi escrito como `\.`. Isso é necessário porque o ponto tem significado especial em regex: [significa "qualquer caractere"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-0) (exceto [quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372844/112052)). Ou seja, se a regex fosse `\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}`, ela pegaria coisas como `12-10#2018` ou até mesmo `12a1092018`, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/3dTBSM) (o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, inclusive letras e números).

Para que o ponto "perca seus poderes" e seja interpretado como um caractere comum, é preciso fazer o *escape* com a `\`. Sendo assim, `\.` corresponde a apenas o caractere `.`, sem nenhum significado especial.

---

Se quiser, também pode usar [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), que retorna um *iterator* de [*matches*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), que podem ser usados para obter mais informações a respeito dos trechos encontrados:

```
for match in r.finditer(texto):
    print("data '{}' encontrada na posicao {}".format(match.group(), match.start()))
```

No exemplo acima usei o [método `group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) para obter o próprio trecho que foi encontrado (no caso, a data) e [`start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start), que retorna a posição da string em que a data foi encontrada:

> data '01.02.2019' encontrada na posicao 5
> data '20.11.2018' encontrada na posicao 28
> data '15.03.1980' encontrada na posicao 57

Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) para mais detalhes sobre as informações que podem ser obtidas do *match*.

Poderíamos parar por aqui, mas como não está claro o que pode ter no seu texto, acho que podemos melhorar mais um pouco essa regex.

---

#### Limitando os valores aceitos

`\d` busca por qualquer dígito de 0 a 9, o que quer dizer que `\d{2}` vai aceitar valores como `00`, `32` e `99`. Mas esses não são valores válidos para dias e meses, então podemos mudar a regex para limitar os valores aceitos:

```
r = re.compile(r'(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19|20)\d{2}')
```

Aqui temos o uso de [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "**ou**"). Ou seja, `abc|xyz` significa "`abc` **ou** `xyz`". Na regex acima, temos vários casos assim para cobrir várias possibilidades de valores. Por exemplo, para o dia, temos 3 possibilidades:

- `0[1-9]`: um zero, seguido de "um dígito de 1 a 9". Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), e o hífen define um intervalo. Portanto, `[1-9]` define um caractere que pode ser qualquer dígito de 1 a 9. Isso garante que o dia pode ser de `01` a `09`
- `[12]\d`: `[12]` também é uma classe de caracteres, mas sem o hífen (e portanto sem um intervalo). No caso, ela significa "o dígito 1 ou 2". Então todo este trecho significa "dígito 1 ou 2, seguido de qualquer dígito". Isso garante que o dia pode ser de `10` a `29`
- `3[01]`: O dígito 3 seguido de 0 ou 1 (para os dias 30 e 31)

O `|` entre essas 3 expressões garante que a regex pode pegar qualquer uma dessas possibilidades, e os parênteses em volta de tudo isso agrupa toda esta sub-expressão em uma coisa só.

Algo parecido foi feito com o mês, sendo que `0[1-9]|1[0-2]` significa:

- `0[1-9]`: zero, seguido de um dígito de 1 a 9 (para os meses de `01` a `09`), **ou**
- `1[0-2]`: dígito 1, seguido de um dígito de 0 a 2 (para os meses `10`, `11` e `12`)

E para o ano, usei `(19|20)\d{2}`, que significa "`19` ou `20`, seguido de 2 dígitos". Ou seja, todos os anos entre 1900 e 2099. Isso é só um exemplo, pode usar `\d{4}` se quiser (lembrando que isso considera valores entre `0000` e `9999`).

Só tem um detalhe: os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e quando isso acontece, `findall` retorna uma lista de tuplas com os grupos. Usando o mesmo texto do exemplo anterior:

```
r = re.compile(r'(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19|20)\d{2}')
print(r.findall(texto))
```

A saída é:

> [('01', '02', '20'), ('20', '11', '20'), ('15', '03', '19')]

Ou seja, uma lista de tuplas, sendo que cada tupla tem o dia, mês e ano separados. Na verdade, o terceiro elemento é somente os dois primeiros dígitos do ano, pois é a parte que está entre parênteses na regex.

Para arrumar isso, basta mudar os parênteses para [grupos de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), colocando `?:` logo depois do `(`. Então a regex fica assim:

```
r = re.compile(r'(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)\d{2}')
print(r.findall(texto))
```

Agora sim o retorno estará correto:

> ['01.02.2019', '20.11.2018', '15.03.1980']

Mas ainda sim, esta regex aceita algumas datas inválidas, como `31.04.2019` (é inválido, pois abril só tem 30 dias), ou ainda `29.02.2019` (inválido porque 2019 não é ano bissexto, então fevereiro de 2019 tem só 28 dias). Não sei como está o seu texto e nem como ele é gerado, mas pode ser que tenha erros de digitação, por exemplo, e nesses casos vale a pena validar as datas.

Embora seja possível fazer uma regex para validar tudo isso (inclusive verificação de anos bissextos), ela é tão complicada que começa a não valer a pena. [Veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768241) um exemplo e tente entendê-lo (talvez como exercício seja interessante, mas eu jamais usaria isso em produção):

`^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$`

Só para entender essa regex já vai demorar um tempo, imagine para dar manutenção...

---

#### Se quiser validar datas, faça fora da regex

Como vimos, uma regex mais simples pode trazer vários trechos que podem não ser datas (como `00.99.1224` ou ainda `31.04.2019`). Já uma regex mais precisa (como a do [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768241) já citado acima) é tão complicada que - na minha opinião - começa a não valer a pena usar, pois é um pesadelo de manutenção.

Talvez o melhor seja um meio-termo: fazer uma regex nem tão complicada, nem tão precisa, mas que traz algo que **pareça** uma data. Em seguida, eu valido esse algo para ter certeza que é de fato uma data válida. Podemos usar a regex já vista, que verifica dias entre 1 e 31, e meses entre 1 e 12, o que já serve como um bom filtro inicial.

Já para validar os casos mais complicados (como anos bissextos e se o mês tem 30 ou 31 dias, etc), podemos usar o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), que possui o [método `strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), que transforma uma string em data (bastando para isso [especificar o formato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) em que esta string está), e caso a data seja inválida, lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Então primeiro podemos criar uma função que verifica se uma string representa uma data no formato "dia.mês.ano":

```
from datetime import datetime

def data_valida(data):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(data, "%d.%m.%Y")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Em seguida, podemos usar essa função com o resultado de `findall`, e descartar os resultados que não são válidos:

```
import re

texto = """Data 01.02.2019, outra data 20.11.2018 etc...
Outra data 15.03.1980, etc
Data inválida: 31.04.2019
"""

r = re.compile(r'(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)\d{2}')

datas = [data for data in r.findall(texto) if data_valida(data)]
print(datas)
```

Com isso, a regex continua encontrando datas inválidas (como `31.04.2019`), mas a função faz uma verificação extra. No final, a lista só terá as datas válidas:

> ['01.02.2019', '20.11.2018', '15.03.1980']

Note que, para criar a lista de datas, eu usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). Mas se quiser, pode usar um *loop* mais "tradicional" e comum à outras linguagens:

```
# O loop abaixo é equivalente a:
# datas = [data for data in r.findall(texto) if data_valida(data)]

datas = []
for data in r.findall(texto):
    if data_valida(data):
        datas.append(data)
print(datas)
```

---

Ainda dá para melhorar mais, claro. Se o seu texto tiver algo como `112.12.2019` (pode ser um erro de digitação, pois possui um `1` a mais no início, mas também pode ser, sei lá, um código específico que por coincidência "se parece" com uma data), a regex vai ignorar o primeiro `1` e pegar o restante (`12.12.2019`).

Se quiser ignorar casos assim, podemos limitar para datas que estejam "isoladas" no texto. Ou seja, sem nenhum outro caractere alfanumérico antes ou depois, e podemos fazer isso usando o atalho `\b` (também chamado de [*word boundary*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26), algo como "fronteira entre palavras" - [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) tem uma explicação mais detalhada):

```
r = re.compile(r'\b(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)\d{2}\b')
```

Com isso, casos como `112.12.2019` são ignorados pela regex.

Só fiz todas essas sugestões porque não ficou claro o que pode estar no seu texto. Dependendo do quão variados estão os seus dados, você pode ajustar a complexidade da regex. O importante é verificar se ela pega o que você precisa, e - não menos importante - se ela não pega o que você não precisa.

Mas como a parte de "não pegar o que não precisa" é mais complicada, ainda acho interessante fazer a validação das datas fora da regex, para ter certeza que são mesmo datas. Mas fica a seu critério fazer isso ou não.

---

(1) No Python 3, [os dígitos aceitos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-27) por `\d` são qualquer caractere da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), o que inclui caracteres como `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`, entre outros (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes, e [este exemplo](https://ideone.com/Ax3Wnn) para entender melhor).

Se quiser que a regex pegue somente dígitos de 0 a 9 (ignorando os demais caracteres como `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`), você pode trocar `\d` por `[0-9]`, ou ainda usar a [flag `ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/IP4Vvm) a diferença):

```
# para \d não considerar outros caracteres de dígitos, use a flag ASCII
r = re.compile(r'\b(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)\d{2}\b',
               flags = re.ASCII)

# ou troque \d por [0-9]
r = re.compile(r'\b(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\b')
```

Claro que, se estiver trabalhando com textos em português, é uma situação mais difícil de acontecer, mas de qualquer forma, fica a dica.

Comment: Geralmente eu me atenho às boas práticas e uso apenas o voto como maneira de gratificar uma boa resposta. Mas dessas vez não. Deus abençoe essa resposta. Ta ótima! Muito obrigado por isso.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva Eu que agradeço seu comentário! De início eu ia só colocar a regex e alguns exemplos, mas achei que valia a pena se aprofundar um pouco mais no assunto (até porque datas são mais complicadas do que parecem). Bom saber que mais gente reconhece a importância de não ficar só no básico e se aprofundar nos detalhes :-)

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado <3

Answer (score 3):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/regex-dot-date?language=python3&folderId=)

> Usando regex:

```
import re
texto = '''
Data de fabricação: 20.02.2019
Validade: 30.12.2099
'''

print(re.findall('\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}',texto))
```

Output:

```
['20.02.2019', '30.12.2099']
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/regex-dot-date?language=python3&folderId=)

Comment: Não esqueã de prefixar a string do reex com `r'` - nesse caso, calhou das sequências de `\` que você usa na regex não serem substituídas pelo Python.