# Dividir uma string em um array de strings a partir da ocorrência de uma data

Tags: javascript, regex, data

Preciso separar uma string, similar ao exemplo abaixo, em um array de strings que comecem a partir da data hora do evento e código do evento (ex: 07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104) e terminasse até a próxima ocorrência.

```
"07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96   ,01/03/2019, 19:20  - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59"
```

Resultado Esperado:

```
1. "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO" 
2. "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento:100"
3. "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99"
4. "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96"
5. "01/03/2019, 19:20 - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59"
```

Tentei utilizar o seguinte código com expressão regular:

```
let eventos = text.split(/\b(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\b/g);
```

Mas ela separa apenas por data, e caso ocorra uma data no meio do evento ele separa o evento em dois.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Existe um padrão para que essa separação seja feita? Você já tentou fazer algum código para isso?

Comment: Luiz, adicionei as informações solicitadas.

Comment: O problema é que nada garante que haverá um padrão específico para a separação desse texto. Esse é um dos problemas ao se trabalhar com strings... Poderíamos até tentar separar pela data, mas veja o último item, por exemplo, que tem uma data (29/03/2019) que não indica uma separação em si, mas algo como uma observação, certo?

Comment: Sua observação esta correta Luiz, por isso quero separar a string pelo padrão data-hora e código, ex :  07/03/2019, 15:43 - 104, pois esse se repete e é único.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso podemos usar uma regex que, em vez de usar a data para o [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), usa uma vírgula, desde que esta seja seguida por "data, hora - código". Assumindo que o código sempre é numérico, uma solução seria:

```js
let str = "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96   ,01/03/2019, 19:20  - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59";

let result = str.split(/,(?=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}\s+-\s+\d+)/).map(s => s.trim());
console.log(result);
```

Repare que usei `\d{2}` e `\d{4}` em vez de `\d+`. O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, ele aceita qualquer quantidade de dígitos. Já usando `{2}` e `{4}` eu garanto que deve ter exatamente estas quantidades (`\d{2}` é "exatamente dois dígitos" e `\d{4}` é "exatamente 4 dígitos"). Caso tenha datas como `1/2/2019`, por exemplo, pode usar `\d{1,2}` (no mínimo 1 e no máximo 2 dígitos).

Eu só usei `\d+` para o código, pois estou assumindo que ele sempre é numérico e o tamanho pode variar. Mas você também pode usar outras variações para definir os tamanhos, se quiser ser mais específico. Exemplos:

- `\d{3}`: exatamente 3 dígitos
- `\d{1,4}`: entre 1 e 4 dígitos
- `\d{3,}`: no mínimo 3 dígitos

Use o que for melhor para o seu caso.

O resultado é:

```
[
  "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO",
  "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100",
  "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99",
  "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96",
  "01/03/2019, 19:20  - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59"
]
```

O truque aqui está no [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), indicado por `(?=....)`. O que ele faz é verificar se algo existe depois da posição atual. Nesse caso, eu estou verificando se tudo dentro do *lookahead* está depois da vírgula. E dentro dele tenho a data, seguida de vírgula, seguido de um espaço, o horário, um ou mais espaços (`\s+`), hífen, um ou mais espaços e um ou mais números (que seriam o código, que estou assumindo que sempre é numérico).

O grande truque do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica se essas coisas existem, [mas elas não fazem parte do *match*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#zero_width), e por isso não são removidas no `split`. Então o `split` só é feito nas vírgulas, mas somente naquelas que possuem a data, hora e código logo depois. As outras vírgulas são ignoradas.

Por fim, eu uso [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) só para eliminar os espaços que ficam no final de cada string.

---

Mas também é possível eliminar o uso de `trim` se incluirmos os espaços no `split`:

```js
let str = "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96   ,01/03/2019, 19:20  - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59";

let result = str.split(/\s*,(?=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}\s+-\s+\d+)/);
console.log(result);
```

Agora a regex verifica zero ou mais espaços (`\s*`) antes da vírgula, então eles também são removidos pelo `split`, e por isso não é mais necessário usar `trim()`.

---

#### Sobre a regex de datas

Eu falo com bem mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052), mas apenas para resumir: usar `\d{2}` aceita valores entre "00" e "99", o que obviamente pode acabar pegando valores que não são datas, sem contar que pode aceitar também valores como 29/02/2019 (sendo que 2019 não é ano bissexto, então nesse ano fevereiro não tem 29 dias).

Se essa string vem de uma fonte confiável/controlada e você sabe que sempre tem datas válidas, a regex acima já é o suficiente. Mas se quiser deixá-la mais precisa, pode usar as sugestões [da resposta que indiquei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052). A parte da data e hora ficaria algo como:

```
(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}, (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)
```

Então o código ficaria:

```js
let str = "07/03/2019, 15:43  - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99   ,07/03/2019, 15:43  - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96   ,01/03/2019, 19:20  - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO -  SILVANO SOUZA)  Prazo: 15 dias  Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59";

let result = str.split(/\s*,(?=(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}, (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)\s+-\s+\d+)/);
console.log(result);
```

Isso ainda não resolve o caso dos anos bissextos, mas já elimina casos em que o dia é maior que 31, meses maiores que 12, minutos maiores que 59, etc. Enfim, ajuste a regex de acordo com o que precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma expressão regular para alcançar o resultado esperado. Apesar de não garantir sucesso caso a string passada não esteja padronizada.

Analisando o padrão da string fornecida na pergunta, fui capaz de criar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}(?= -)/g
```

Ao a destrinchar, podemos determinar que:

- `\d{2}` e `\d{4}` ⇒ dois e quatro números seguidos, respectivamente;
- `\/` ⇒ uma barra (`/`);
- `(?= -)` ⇒ um [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (faz com que a expressão só dê match caso tenha um espaço seguido de hífen na frente da data ( `-`).

No entanto, não basta usar o `split` para que solucionemos o problema, já que este método remove as datas encontradas que dividem a string. Como nós não queremos que as datas iniciais (que são responsáveis por dividir a string), precisamos também usar o método `match` para capturá-las e uni-las depois.

Algo assim:

```js
function splitString(input) {
  const regex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}(?= -)/g
  const matches = input.match(regex)

  return (splittedInput = input
    // Divide a string com base na expressão regular definida acima.
    .split(regex)
    // Remove strings vazias:
    .filter((s) => !!s)
    // Junta os matches com as divisões, já que o split remove o match e nós não
    // queremos esse comportamento.
    .map((value, i) => `${matches[i]} ${value.trim()}`))
}

console.log(
  splitString(
    '07/03/2019, 15:43 - 104. PETIÇÃO PROTOCOLADA JUNTADA - Refer. aos Eventos: 96, 99 e 100 - CIÊNCIA, COM RENÚNCIA AO PRAZO   ,07/03/2019, 15:43 - 103. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 100   ,07/03/2019, 15:43 - 102. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 99   ,07/03/2019, 15:43 - 101. Intimação Eletrônica - Confirmada - Refer. ao Evento: 96   ,01/03/2019, 19:20 - 100. Intimação Eletrônica - Expedida/Certificada - Julgamento (APELADO - SILVANO SOUZA) Prazo: 15 dias Data final: ,29/03/2019, 23:59:59'
  )
)
```

- [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split);
- [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).