# Verificar data válida no oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle11c

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou tentando trazer as datas válidas do banco pois tem datas com formatos inválidos no mesmo, abaixo segue o código que estou utilizando, alguém pode me dar uma mão? Já fiz de tudo...

```
SELECT b.mec_dtmovi,
   CASE                   
     WHEN regexp_like(b.mec_dtmovi,'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)') THEN
       to_date(b.mec_dtmovi,'dd/mm/yyyy') 
      ELSE 
        null END

     FROM VIS_MECDIG b
```

O resultado fica assim com o lado direito em branco, ele sempre vai para else:

MEC_DTMOVI    CASEWHENREGEXP_LIKE(B.MEC_DTMO
17/03/2014
17/03/2014
20/03/2014
27/03/2014
20/03/2014
20/03/2014
27/03/2014
28/03/2014
28/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
27/03/2014
17/03/2014
28/03/2014
28/03/2014
27/03/2014

Fiz a função mostrada abaixo:

```
create or replace function valida_data(v_data varchar2) return varchar2 is

v_data1 date;

begin 

select to_date(v_data) into v_data1 from dual;
return v_data;
exception
when value_error then
return null;  
end;
```

Mas estou tendo problemas ao usar o select com where, quando uso alguma função do oracle para somar ou subtrair dias com sysdate ou não e etc, como não manjo muito de oracle pesquisei bastante mas não achei nada que resolvesse meu problema, abaixo está o select que usei, sendo que cadastrei de proposito no campo de data que é do tipo varchar na tabela caracteres inválidos como ponto, interrogação e etc... Para ver se a função iria trazer a data mesmo assim, pois no cenário que estou preciso que traga as datas válida e as que não forem válidas terá que ficar null ou mostrar alguma mensagem no campo com a data que tenha o caractere inválido ou formato errado.
Lembrado que está dificuldade é porque o campo é varchar2 em vez de date um erro de modelagem do banco porém a empresa não quer mudar nem o banco nem o front nem o back-end permitindo assim o usuário por caracteres inválidos no campo...

```
SELECT * FROM TB_TESTE_DATA_01 WHERE teste_data(data_admissao) = trunc(sysdate);
```

Alguém pode ajudar este pobre homem aqui?

Comment: Não use regex para validar datas, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) para entender porque isso não é uma boa ideia. No Oracle acho que é mais fácil usar as próprias funções de data, exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14702163

Comment: @hkotsubo, editei minha pergunta e acrescentei a função que tinha citado, porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: select to_date(v_data,'DD/MM/YYYY') into v_data1 from dual;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver depois de horas testando, mas Deus é bom o tempo todo e me permitiu achar a solução, abaixo segue a solução:

```
SELECT * FROM  TB_TESTE_DATA_01 b WHERE  b.DATA_ADMISSAO = 
(CASE 
WHEN regexp_like(DATA_ADMISSAO,'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.] 
(19|20)') THEN 
    b.DATA_ADMISSAO
      ELSE 
       NULL 
   END) AND b.data_admissao <= TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Ou assim:

```
SELECT b.data_admissao, CASE WHEN regexp_like(DATA_ADMISSAO,'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)') THEN 
    b.DATA_ADMISSAO   
      ELSE 
       'data errada'
   END FROM  TB_TESTE_DATA_01 b WHERE  b.DATA_ADMISSAO = 
(CASE 
WHEN regexp_like(DATA_ADMISSAO,'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]) 
[- /.](19|20)') THEN 
    b.DATA_ADMISSAO   
      ELSE 
       'data errada'
   END)
```

Ficou meio tosco mas funcionou perfeitamente, caso dê erro usando o SQLPlus retire o 'data errada' do ELSE e ponha o NULL.
Se alguém tiver uma forma melhor de fazer isso por favor me mostre, sou novo com Oracle e SQL...
Lembrado que está dificuldade é porque o campo é varchar2 em vez de date um erro de modelagem do banco porém a empresa não quer mudar nem o banco nem o front nem o back-end permitindo assim o usuário por caracteres inválidos no campo...

Comment: Se colocar 31/02/2022 essa validação vai deixar passar.