# Obter data de uma string

Tags: java, regex, data

Estou tentando criar uma expressão regular que retorne algumas datas contidas em strings. Os formatos são:

- dd/MM/yyyy
- dd-MM-yyyy
- dd/MM
- dd-MM

Ex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String text1 = "Foo bar foo bar foo bar 29/01/2021 foo bar foo bar";

    final String text2 = "Foo bar foo bar 29-01-2021 foo bar foo bar";

    final String text3 = "Foo bar foo bar 29/01 foo bar foo bar";

    final String text4 = "Foo bar foo bar 29-01 foo bar foo bar";

    // result 29/01/2021
    final String date1 = getDate(text1);

    // result 29-01-2021
    final String date2 = getDate(text2);

    // result 29/01
    final String date3 = getDate(text3);

    // result 29-01
    final String date4 = getDate(text4);

}

private static String getDate(final String text) {
    return "Magic";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052), uma regex pode ajudar a encontrar algo que se **pareça** com uma data, mas ainda será importante validá-la - leia o link já indicado para mais detalhes, mas de maneira resumida, uma data possui regras complexas demais para serem validadas por uma regex (como a quantidade variável de dias em um mês, principalmente para fevereiro em anos bissextos).

Então você pode usar a regex para obter o trecho que contém uma possível data, e em seguida validá-lo com as ferramentas específicas (no caso, uma API de datas). Algo assim:

```
private static Pattern POSSIBLE_DATE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{2}[-/]\\d{2}([-/]\\d{4})?\\b");
private static DateTimeFormatter DMY = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM[-uuuu]][dd/MM[/uuuu]]").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

static String getDate(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = POSSIBLE_DATE_REGEX.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) { // se encontrou, valida a data
        String possivelData = matcher.group();
        try {
            DMY.parseBest(possivelData, LocalDate::from, MonthDay::from);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // data inválida (se quiser, imprima o erro: System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return possivelData;
    }

    // se não encontrou, retorna null
    return null;
}

...
System.out.println(getDate(text1)); // 29/01/2021
System.out.println(getDate(text2)); // 29-01-2021
System.out.println(getDate(text3)); // 29/01
System.out.println(getDate(text4)); // 29-01
```

A ideia é pegar algo que se pareça com uma data: 2 dígitos (`\d{2}`), seguido de barra ou hífen (`[-/]`) e mais 2 dígitos (e opcionalmente, outra barra ou hífen e mais 4 dígitos - o `?` após deste trecho [torna-o opcional](http://regular-expressions.info/optional.html)). Em volta da expressão eu coloco `\b` (explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052)) para garantir que não haja outro dígito antes ou depois (assim evito casos como `123456/789`, pois se não tivesse o `\b` a regex acabaria pegando o trecho "56/78").

Mas como essa regex também pode pegar coisas como "99/99/9999" (que é uma data inválida), e no [link já indicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) é explicado como seria difícil fazer uma regex mais precisa, eu prefiro usar a API de datas (no caso, o [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), disponível a partir do Java 8) para verificar se a data é válida.

Para isso eu uso *patterns* opcionais (indicado pelos `[ ]`), então `[dd-MM[-uuuu]][dd/MM[/uuuu]]` diz que posso ter "dia-mês" (com "-ano" opcional) ou "dia/mês" (com "/ano" opcional).

Depois, no `parseBest` eu passo as possibilidades de objetos que podem ser criados (`LocalDate` e `MonthDay`, respectivamente classes que possuem dia, mês e ano, ou somente dia e mês). Se alguma delas conseguir ser construída, é porque a data é válida. Senão, é lançada uma exceção.

Para os casos em que não há uma data, ou ela é inválida, estou retornando `null`.

---

#### Java <= 7

Para Java <= 7, o `java.time` não está disponível, então você tem que usar `SimpleDateFormat`. A ideia é similar:

```
private static List<SimpleDateFormat> FORMATS = Arrays.asList(createFormat("dd-MM"), createFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"), createFormat("dd/MM"), createFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));

private static SimpleDateFormat createFormat(String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    sdf.setLenient(false); // para validar corretamente as datas
    return sdf;
}

static String getDate(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = POSSIBLE_DATE_REGEX.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) { // se encontrou, valida a data
        String possivelData = matcher.group();
        for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : FORMATS) {
            try {
                sdf.parse(possivelData);
                return possivelData;// se deu certo, não precisa testar os outros formatos
            } catch (ParseException e) {}
        }
        // se todos forem inválidos, é porque não encontrou
        return null;
    }

    // se não encontrou, retorna null
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: Excelente resposta. Pequeno adendo, quando as *patterns* ou configurações de *parsing* se tornam complexas a classe [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) pode ajudar a construir um `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Sim, eu também fiz uma versão com o builder, mas neste caso específico não vi muita vantagem: https://ideone.com/k69yHi - quando há somente campos opcionais, os colchetes já resolvem bem, eu costumo usar o builder [em outros casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+DateTimeFormatterBuilder) :-)