# Como formular o Pattern para limitar data

Tags: javascript, html, data

Estou desenvolvendo um site em que o usuário precisa pesquisar por rotas de motoristas de lotação, e nessa pesquisa eu quero limitar as datas que ele pode utilizar para por exemplo, no mínimo o dia atual e no máximo 2 anos a frente.

Sei que posso utilizar o "Pattern" para especificar, mas até o momento o que consigo fazer com esse recurso é:

```
pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
```

Mas isso não é suficiente.

Outro problema que estou enfrentando é quando são os `<input type="date">` que são o tipo de máscara padrão do HTML, mas que tem uma falha bem chata.

Primeiro que ele funciona perfeitamente as duas primeiras partes que são de `dd/mm` mas a terceira parte que é a do ano ele não funciona direito, em vez de limitar a 4 dígitos, ou seja, `12/12/2000`, ele permite 6 dígitos no ano tipo `12/12/200000` e não sei como consertar isso, porque nos campos que deixo do tipo `text` a máscara funciona perfeitamente, mas nesse tipo `date` não dá.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já não sei o que fazer porque utilizar o campo `"type="text"` com máscara não é bem o que eu queria para a performance do site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em um `input type="date"`, é possível limitar os valores mínimo e máximo. Por exemplo, para aceitar apenas anos com 4 dígitos, você pode colocar o valor máximo como sendo 31 de dezembro de 9999 (lembrando que a data deve estar no formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)):

```html
<input type="date" max="9999-12-31" name="data">
```

---

Mas na pergunta é dito que se quer "*no mínimo o dia atual e no máximo 2 anos a frente*". Então os valores mínimo e máximo são dinâmicos, por isso você deve setá-los via JavaScript. Ex:

```js
function pad(valor) { // completa com zeros à esquerda, caso necessário
    return valor.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function formata(data) {
    return `${data.getFullYear()}-${pad(data.getMonth() + 1)}-${pad(data.getDate())}`;
}

const campo = document.querySelector('#campoData');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var data = new Date(); // data de hoje
    campo.min = formata(data);
    // 2 anos à frente
    data.setFullYear(data.getFullYear() + 2);
    campo.max = formata(data);
});

// mensagens de validação
campo.addEventListener('input', () => {
  campo.setCustomValidity('');
  campo.checkValidity();
});

// se tentar submeter o form com data fora do intervalo, mostra o erro
campo.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('A data deve estar entre hoje e 2 anos à frente');
});
```

```css
/* deixar borda vermelha enquanto o campo for inválido */
input:invalid {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="campoData" type="date" name="data">
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date), os valores sempre devem ser setados no já citado formato ISO 8601 ("aaaa-mm-dd"), por isso criei as funções para auxiliar na formatação.

Depois setei os valores mínimo e máximo de acordo com as regras indicadas (mínimo = data atual, máximo = data atual + 2 anos).

---

**Detalhe importante:** o comportamento do `input type="date"` é dependente do *browser*. Muitos mostram um calendário quando você clica no campo - por exemplo, no Chrome fica assim:

[image: calendário quando você clica no input type=date]

Repare que as datas anteriores à hoje ficam esmaecidas e não acontece nada se clicar nelas.

Mas nada impede que se **digite** uma data inválida diretamente no campo. Por isso no exemplo acima eu adicionei um CSS para deixar a borda vermelha caso o valor seja inválido (apenas para que você possa visualizar que o *browser* detecta quando o valor está fora dos limites estabelecidos), além de não deixar o *form* ser submetido (digite uma data fora do intervalo permitido e depois tente clicar no botão "ok").

Mas claro que esta parte mais "visual" seria apenas para ajudar o usuário, pois [você também deveria validar a data recebida no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052).

---

Por fim, não use regex para isso. Regex lida basicamente com texto (mesmo dígitos como `1` e `2` são tratados como meros caracteres), então fazer comparações numéricas (como saber se o ano está entre o atual e 2 anos à frente) é bem complicado e não vale a pena (só para citar um exemplo, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363660/112052) como a regex pode acabar ficando bem complicada, caso você realmente queira validar qualquer data possível).

Comment: Acredito que isso resolve meu problema temporáriamente. Valeu pela ajuda, essa validação é bem complexa pra meu nível de JavaScript, então fico meio perdido com algumas coisas.

Comment: @GildevanPereira Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Comment: @GildevanPereira De qualquer forma, se os valores mínimo e máximo são dinâmicos (variam conforme a data atual), não tem muito como fugir do JavaScript :-)

Comment: Esse código me ajudou muito mas agora como eu faço pra utilizar esse código para o campo de data de retorno?

Answer (score 1):

Faltou algumas coisas no pattern que você esta utilizando, primeiramente o caracter `/` precisa de escape para funcionar corretamente, outro ponto é que você precisar indicar que sua string deverá conter somente esses caracteres, do começo ao fim.
Fiz alguns testes e cheguei nesse resultado:

```
const pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/

pattern.test("07/02/2021") // true
pattern.test("08/02/20202112") // false
```

Basicamente o caracter `^` indica o começo da linha, enquanto o caracter `$` indica o fim da linha, sendo assim você consegue garantir que sua `string` conterá somente os caracteres que atendem a regra informada.

OBS: Esse patern não irá validar casos como `07/13/2020` ou `40/20/4500`, essas entradas serão consideradas válidas.