# Por que utilizar o re.compile? Qual a diferença entre usar apenas o pattern desejado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Podemos encontrar alguma diferença ao utilizar o re.compile dentro do Python?

Supondo um arquivo com 10 linhas compostas por datas e um arquivo de 10000 linhas de datas.
Um pattern poderia ser `pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}')`
e o segundo apenas o match 
`re.match('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', 'variavel_para_arquivo')`

Comment: Talvez pelo fato de `re.compile` retornar um objeto, você pode reutilizá-lo em para verificar outras strings.

Comment: Sobre `re.compile`, a duplicada sugerida acima já explica bem. Sobre usar regex para datas, sugiro uma lida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363660/112052